# Finding 8 neighbours in 2d Array

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I have looked around for this question, there are some answers about the question, but none that i really understand/or is not suitable for me.

So my problem is to check for 8 neighbors in an 2d array containing chars, either * or O.

Code:

```
aliveCheck = isAlive(g,row,column-1);
if(aliveCheck){
    aliveCounter++;
}

aliveCheck = isAlive(g,row,column+1);
if(aliveCheck == 1){
    aliveCounter++;
}

aliveCheck = isAlive(g,row+1,column);
if(aliveCheck == 1){
    aliveCounter++;
}
```

Etc for all the 8 neighbours, this works, but I'm not happy with the solution.

isAlive() is a simple function to findout if a coordinate is * or O.

Anyone got a better solution to this problem or got any tips on how to improve it?

Thanks

Comment: In what way are you `unhappy` with the solution?

Comment: You could try looping with row and column offsets and writing one block of code that adds the offets and only changing the offsets each loop.

Comment: The code gets really long when there are 8 if statements after each other, and im interested in learning some new ways to aproach this problem @nhgrif

Comment: just put it in a function. To me, using the loop method described in the answers makes it more confusing of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Out of curiosity, trying to solve Conway's game of life?

Comment: @RhinoFeeder Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=-1, i<=1; ++i) {
    for(int j=-1; j<=1; ++j {
        if((i || j) && isAlive(g,row+i,column+j)) {
            aliveCounter++; } } }
```

This method assumes that `i-1`, `i+1`, `j-1`, and `j+1` are all within the bounds of your array.

It should also be noted that while this approach accomplishes what you're trying to accomplish in a very few number of lines, it's far less readable.  As such, this approach should be accompanied with very descriptive comments.  Moreover, this approach (or any other method) would be best wrapped in an appropriately named function (such as `checkNeighbors`).

Comment: I was just about to say that! OP: Watch your boundaries on the array.

Comment: You could say 'if(i && j && isAlive(g,row+i,column+j) { ... }'

Comment: Hmm, really good point @CharlieBurns  Except, should be `(i || j) && isAlive(/*etc*/)`

Comment: No, but I understood what you meant.  ;)

Comment: This also checks at `row,column` (not sure if that is acceptable)

Comment: @clcto No it doesn't.  If `i` and `j` are both `0`, then `(i || j)` returns `false` and so the `&&` we're checking in the `if` statement returns `false` and `aliveCounter` is not incremented.

Comment: @nhgrif you have if `i==0 || j==0` ... oh you just changed it.

Comment: Or even just two loops and "aliveCounter += (i || j) && isAlive(g,row+i,column+j); That may be getting kind of ugly.