# Finding neighbor in 2D array using delta

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I was going through one of the online courses for Data strudcture and Algorithms. There I saw saw a topic "Delta based two dimensional array search". Which describes below:

- A techinque to search adjoing array elements of four directions in coordinates of two directions.
- Delta value is an array that saves coordinates of four direction in coordinates as well as difference between X and Y.
- Delta value is employed to approach the elements located up down left right side of certain element.

As per m understanding, its basically searching neighbors in four directions of a given array. I found couple of good answers on stack overflow:

- [Finding the neighbors of 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816484/finding-the-neighbors-of-2d-array)
- [Finding 8 neighbours in 2d Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778973/finding-8-neighbours-in-2d-array)
- [Finding a neighbour in a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556568/finding-a-neighbour-in-a-2d-array)
- [More efficient way to check neighbours in a two-dimensional array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120609/more-efficient-way-to-check-neighbours-in-a-two-dimensional-array-in-java)
- [Finding neighbours in a two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652106/finding-neighbours-in-a-two-dimensional-array/4271763)

  However I am not clear with the 2nd point "***Delta value is an array that saves coordinates of four direction in coordinates as well as difference between X and Y***". Can anyone explain what does this point means? Also the stack overflow links that I mentioned above serve the purpose? Thank You